# Regexp, strings between string

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

So string looks like that:

```
 abc_#xoxo#_xyz
```

I want to pull out everyting except _#*#_ and get them in two match results (abc and xyz). I made a regexp to get stuff from inside:

```
 (?<=_#)[^}]*(?=#_)
```

I have struggled with it for quite a while and have no idea how to catch that, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is a very easy task.

```
(.*)_#.*#_(.*)
```

Link: http://rubular.com/r/iymHrETOlU

Here's some ruby code

```
s = 'abc_#xoxo#_xyz'
regex = /(.*)_#.*#_(.*)/

match = regex.match(s)
match[1] # => "abc"
match[2] # => "xyz"
```